Excel - Count Number of Rows Value X Appears In Where Column A Equals Y
I have the following dataset which is trimmed down here. It has about 3K rows where it repeats the same section over and over, but the values are slightly different. The colors repeat and never change, but the values in B:G may change for each color.
I am attempting to count the number of rows a value, such as Oscar, appears in, for each color. For the example dataset here, Oscar would receive the value of 1 for the color Red because of the two rows where Red is the color, he appears in only one of those rows. Likewise, he would receive a 2 for the color Purple because he appears in 2 rows that are the color Purple.
The difficulty I am having is I keep falling back to doing a count of the number of times the name appears for a color. Closest I've got is this below where K22:K30 are a list of colors and Q21:30 are the names.
=COUNT(IF(FILTER($A:$G,$K22=$A:$A)=Q$21,1,""))

Any help is appreciated, thanks.



A
B
C
D
E
F
G




Blue
John
Brian
Steve
Dale
Brady
Lane


Green
Steve
Dale
Kyle
Kyle
Kyle
Kyle


Red
Steve
James
James
James
Dale
Dale


Yellow
John
Brian
Brian
Brian
John
John


Orange
John
Peter
Dave
Dave
Dave
Dave


Purple
John
Peter
Peter
Peter
Oscar
Oscar


Pink
Dale
Steve
Oscar
Oscar
Oscar
Oscar


Black
Mike
Mike
Mike
Mike
Dale
Kyle


Cyan
Austin
Austin
Austin
Dale
Steve
Steve




















Blue
John
Brian
Steve
Dale
Brady
Lane


Green
Steve
Dale
Kyle
Kyle
Kyle
Kyle


Red
Oscar
Oscar
Oscar
Oscar
Oscar
Oscar


Yellow
John
Brian
Brian
Brian
John
John


Orange
John
Peter
Dave
Dave
Dave
Dave


Purple
John
Peter
Peter
Peter
Oscar
Oscar


Pink
Dale
Steve
Oscar
Oscar
Oscar
Oscar


Black
Mike
Mike
Mike
Mike
Dale
Kyle


Cyan
Austin
Austin
Austin
Dale
Steve
Steve




Edit: This seems like you are looking for the following counts, if I am not mistaken here: (FILTER() function is redundant not needed, I followed the formula in OP, so realized later)


• Method 1: Using MMULT()
=SUM(--(MMULT(($I3=$B$1:$G$18)*(J$2=$A$1:$A$18),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS($B$1:$G$1)))>0))


• Method 2: Using BYROW() with LAMBDA() construct
=SUM(N(BYROW(($I3=$B$1:$G$18)*(J$2=$A$1:$A$18),LAMBDA(x,OR(x)))))


• Method 3: Using BYROW() with ETA LAMBDA construct
=SUM(N(BYROW(($I3=$B$1:$G$18)*(J$2=$A$1:$A$18),OR)))


You can also use MAKEARRAY() to return one single dynamic array formula:


=LET(
     _Data, A1:G18,
     _Colors, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _Names, DROP(_Data,,1),
     _UniqC, TOROW(UNIQUE(_Colors)),
     _UniqN, UNIQUE(TOCOL(_Names)),
     _Counts, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_UniqN),COLUMNS(_UniqC), LAMBDA(r,c,
             SUM(--(MMULT((INDEX(_UniqN,r)=_Names)*(INDEX(_UniqC,c)=_Colors),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(_Data)-1))>0)))),
     HSTACK(VSTACK("",_UniqN), VSTACK(_UniqC, _Counts)))


